# Random gradient background color

Tags: javascript, css, background-color, linear-gradients

i'm trying to get a random gradient background (between 4 colours) on each section.
This is my code:

```js
let colors = ["#ffd0d2","#fffdd0","#d0fffd","#d0d2ff"];
    $(".main").children('section').each(function(){   
        let firstGradient = randomNumber(10,90);
        $(this).css(
            "background", "linear-gradient(141deg, "+colors[randomNumber(0,4)]+" "+firstGradient+"%, "+colors[randomNumber(0,4)]+" "+(100-firstGradient)+"%)"
        );
    });
    function randomNumber(min,max){
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
    }
```

```css
section{
  display:block;
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

It is so random. Sometimes i get results like this:
[image]

When result should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: @j08691 Well i agree, but thats not true on this case.
I mean, I can get 10% and 90% but gradiend should work anyway. (On some cases there is no "blur" between both colors

Comment: You changed your question, invalidates my answer a bit .... you shouldnt change the question after accepting an answer (or even after one is posted if it invalidates it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont try to calculate the remaining `%` then it seems to work as you expect

```js
let colors = ["#ffd0d2","#fffdd0","#d0fffd","#d0d2ff"];
    $(".main").children('section').each(function(){   
        let firstGradient = randomNumber(10,90);
        $(this).css(
            "background", "linear-gradient(141deg, "+colors[randomNumber(0,4)]+" "+firstGradient+"%, "+colors[randomNumber(0,4)] + ")"
        );
    });
    function randomNumber(min,max){
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
    }
```

```css
section{
  display:block;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, but why? I mean why your answer work? ^^

Comment: @KaSkuLL because randomly sometimes you'll get 50%

Answer (score 0):

```js
let colors = ["#ffd0d2","#fffdd0","#d0fffd","#d0d2ff"];
    $(".main").children('section').each(function(){   
        let firstGradient = randomNumber(10,40);
        $(this).css(
            "background", "linear-gradient(141deg, "+colors[randomNumber(0,4)]+" "+firstGradient+"%, "+colors[randomNumber(0,4)]+" "+(100-firstGradient)+"%)"
        );
        "background", "linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%)" 
    });
    function randomNumber(min,max){
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
    }
```

```css
section{
  display:block;
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

If your first gradient position is bigger then 50%, the second is smaller then first.
for example gradient from red 60% to green 40% will be a straight line. 
fixed your randomNumber to always be <50

And obviously you get no blur when gradient from and to are the same color